# Sum of a subspace and the linear span of a single vector. Is it closed?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Consider $G_0$ to be a subspace of a Banach space and $y_1 \notin G_0$. Is the set $\{ z + \alpha y_1, z \in G_0, \alpha \in \mathbb R \}$ a subspace, i.e., is it a closed linear manifold?

The question is motivated by the proof of Theorem 2 in Section 32 of the first volume of Kolmogorov and Fomin's Elements of the theory of functions and functional analysis (p.119 of the Martino edition).
There $G_0 =\{x-Ax, \forall x\in E\}$, where E is a Banach space and A a (continuous) operator. The authors first prove that $G_0$ is closed, then consider the set $\{ z + \alpha y_1, z \in G_0 \}$ and say it is a subspace. The fact that this is a subspace is important for later application of the Hahn-Banach theorem.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy, no $alpha$ is any real value

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Yes $G_0$ is closed. By definition in Kolmogorov&Fomin a subspace is a closed linear manifold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $z_n+\alpha_n y_1 \to u$. If $|\alpha_n | \to \infty$ then we get $\frac {z_n} {\alpha_n} +y_1 \to 0$. This implies that $\frac {z_n} {\alpha_n} \to -y_1$. But $G_0$ is closed, so $-y_1 \in G_0$, a contradiction. Now the same argument with a subsequence shows that $(\alpha_n)$ cannot be unbounded. But if it is bounded then there is a convergent subsequence. Can you now finish the proof by showing that $u \in \{z+\alpha y_1: z\in G_0, \alpha \in F\}$ ?

Comment: I see that in the proof of Hahn-Banach theorem, Kolmogorov&Fomin are progressively extending a subspace by adding the span of a single vector, and they claim this is also a subspace (then closed according to their definition), but why is it so?

Comment: I just added a proof. @Giovanni

Comment: Yes I can complete the proof. Thanks a lot!